# ¿Como hago para usar un evento dentro de una "clase" javascript, desde el mouseup de un contenedor?

Tags: javascript, eventos, clase

```
        function MakeDrawable(containerID){
            this.container = (document.getElementById(containerID) || document.body);
            this.onCreateElement = null;//Evento externo
            this.container.onmouseup = function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var hash = {Nombre:"Hola", Apellido: "Mundo"};
                //Quiero llamar a mi evento externo
                this.onCreateElement(hash);
            }
        }
        //Implementacion

        var drawableContainer = new MakeDrawable("qa");
        drawableContainer.onCreateElement = function(hash){
            alert(JSON.stringify(hash));
        };
```

¡De antemano muchas gracias por su tiempo!

La pregunta del titulo se que es medio confusa, pero el código explica bien mi duda.

Mi idea con esto es, realizar la implementación y usar el evento bindeandole una función creada por mi, que ésta reciba un argumento.
La cosa es que no me está funcionando, no se como accesar desde el mouseup del contenedor al evento *onCreateElement* que tengo en mi clase *MakeDrawable*, manteniendo el hilo de ejecucion de cada *new* que haga sobre la clase.

Muchas gracias!

Edit: Ignorar los *punto y coma* o *llaves* ya que el código lo recorté para tener el caso especifico. Me interesa la parte del llamado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas noches respondiendo mi propia pregunta, dejo un código de ejemplo donde instancio clases Javascript y puedo hacer un call a los eventos asignados desde afuera.

Saludos y espero que les sirva!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Test

```
    <script>
        function XCore(iContainer){
            var XCore = this;
            this.Container = iContainer;
            this.TextBox = _TextBox;

            function _TextBox(name){
                var TextBox = this;
                this.Name = name;
                this.Control = _Control;
                this.Render = _Render;
                this.ChangeClass = "";

                this.KeyPress = function(){};


                function _Control(){
                    var inputText;

                    if(typeof(document.getElementById(TextBox.Name)) == "undefined" || (typeof(document.getElementById(TextBox.Name)) == "object" && document.getElementById(TextBox.Name) == null )){
                        inputText = document.createElement("input");
                        inputText.setAttribute("type","text");
                        inputText.setAttribute("id",TextBox.Name);
                        inputText.setAttribute("name",TextBox.Name);
                    }

                    return document.getElementById(TextBox.Name) || inputText;
                }

                function _Render(){
                    var container = document.getElementById(XCore.Container) || document.body;
                    container.setAttribute("class", "Container");
                    container.appendChild(TextBox.Control());

                    TextBox.Control().onkeypress = TextBox.KeyPress;
                    TextBox.Control().setAttribute("class",TextBox.ChangeClass);
                }
            }
        }

    </script>
    <style>
        .Container{
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
        }
        .TextBox{
            clear: both;
            float: left;
            display: block;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 200px;
            margin-top: 5px;

        }
        .TextBox.Red{
            border: 1px solid #FF0000;
            background: #F0F0F0;
            color: #A0A0A0;
        }
        .TextBox.Blue{
            border: 1px solid #00AAFF;
            background: #FFFFFF;
            color: #A0A0A0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>
        var core = new XCore();
        var nombre = new core.TextBox("nombre");
        nombre.ChangeClass = "TextBox Red";
        nombre.Render();

        var apellido = new core.TextBox("apellido");
        apellido.ChangeClass = "TextBox Blue";
        apellido.KeyPress = function (e){
            alert(e.which);
        };
        apellido.Render();
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

No es posible hacerlo de la manera que quieres.
Por ejemplo en el método de **onmouseup**, cuando quieres enviar el **hash** a **onCreateElement** el ***this*** en ese momento no es el de la clase y por eso te salta un error. El ambito de this en este método cambia.
Mira lo que yo hice con tu código.

```
function MakeDrawable(containerID){
        let self = this;
        this.container = (document.getElementById(containerID) || document.body);
        this.onCreateElement = function(hash) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(hash))
        };//Evento externo
        this.container.onmouseup = function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var hash = {Nombre:"Hola", Apellido: "Mundo"};
            //Quiero llamar a mi evento externo
            self.onCreateElement(hash);
        }
    }
    //Implementacion

    var drawableContainer = new MakeDrawable("qa");
```

Capture el this de la clase en la variable **self** para poder refenciar this en el método onmouseup.
Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta! Claro, en ese caso mantenes la referencia y lo usas. Mi idea sería otra, instaciar y usar el metodo como si fuera un evento luego de instanciarlo.Ya que este es un evemto que se carga cuando se crea un nuevo div.

var drawableContainer = new MakeDrawable("qa");
drawableContainer.onCreateElement(function(e){
Ajax
});

Si quisiera bindear un evento creado por mi (new CustomEvent), al window como quedaría?